# API test report?

Tags: rest, api, jenkins, postman, newman

I’ve been working as an API test engineer for four months. I’m creating API testing framework from scratch. I use Postman to maintain and store my test scripts and use Newman to run my test collection on Jenkins server. But I don’t receive good reports about test results and my manager requires providing graphical weekly and monthly reports about API testing. When I was working as a GUI test automation engineer I used Allure report and I was more than happy with it because I received graphical information about my tests. And I really need kinda the same result for my API testing. Does anybody know how can I do it? If you know how can I get similar result like on screenshot just provide me the name of the tool or basic plan and I will be happy. Thanks!

***attached screenshot is allure report. I use it to get report about Selenium web-driver test results. [Example of report that I expect but for API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g88qg.png)

Comment: Don't make one. Use one. There are a lot of them out there already made. Eg: Chakram, Dredd, Assertible.

Answer (score 0):

When i was testing, my company had this software to help me with testing:

https://www.soapui.org/

But it is not free.

Best

Answer (score 0):

I use console.log statements in my postman test scripts. When I run the tests with newman, I capture these statements in a file. This is one way of reporting each failure (or whatever you wish to report). In my case I am formatting the output as a comma-delimited output, so I can import into excel and organize that way.

I compile summary reports by using newman as a nodeJS module. As the test is running, I use the [events](https://www.npmjs.com/package/newman#newmanrunevents) to capture statistics such as response time for each request. I can capture additional information about requests that timed out or failed. When the collection is finished, I can calculate average response times, overall error rate, etc and persist the summary report to a file.